# Sort using overriden method compare

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator

I am trying to sort items by the price, but each item belongs to a category so I have to create a map with categories as key and items as value and I have to sort it using `Comparator` class.

This is `Comparator` class

```java
public class ProductionSorter implements Comparator<Item> {
    public ProductionSorter(){};

    @Override
    public int compare (Item a, Item b){
        return a.getSellingPrice().compareTo(b.getSellingPrice());
    }
}
```

This is the map

```java
Map <Category, List<Item>> mapOfItems = items
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getCategory));
```

I am not sure how to sort items by price on this map.

Comment: The prices of the items are in the list , which of those prices will you sort by ?

Answer (score 4):

The following should do the trick:

```java
Map<String, List<Item>> mapOfItems = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getCategory,
                collectingAndThen(toList(), e -> e.stream().sorted(new ProductionSorter()).collect(toList()))));
```

With the following imports:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

It is similar to what you have already but with the additional `Collector` so that you can define how you want your data to be collected.

You can read more about the `collectingAndThen()` at the [reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this e -> e.stream... is giving me problems. I'm getting an error "Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: expected List<Object> but found List<Item>".

Comment: That is weird, this is working on my side. Maybe you imported the wrong classes? I've added my imports to the answer. Please check them ;)